# if checkbox is marked, then create msgbox with form value in access

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba, ms-access-2007

So I have an access form based on a table. The form has a list of colors and a yes/no checkbox next to it. If the user marks the checkboxes then clicks a button, i want a msgbox to appear to show all the colors next to the marked checkboxes. Here is the code I currently have, it does not run if I click the button a second time. It also sometimes only shows the first color and is buggy in general.

Form looks like this

Red     x
Blue
Green   x
Yellow  x

Code looks like this

```
private sub command5_click()
dim rs as dao.recordset  
set rs=me.recordsetclone  

rs.movefirst  
do while not rs.eof  

if rs!checkboxes = true then  
  msgbox rs!color  
end if  
rs.movenext  
loop  
set rs=nothing  

end sub
```

Comment: That will not work unless you requery the recordset. Yes, changes are made to the data when focus is lost, but the recordset needs to be updated via a refresh or requery.

Comment: How is your form set up? Continuous forms?

Comment: yes continuous forms, sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: So the checkbox is **not** a field in the table, is it? It's just a control? Btw, when more than 1 person comment, you need to @ their name so they get notified. Like, @barker.

Comment: @Invent-Animate oh i see :) yes the checkbox is a field in the table. I think i got it working! None of the code in either of my two questions worked exactly, but i had to tinker with it and it works now.

Comment: @barker Good. FYI - those are all things that you should tell people in your post. It just gives them accurate info to work with. It will come with time. You should post what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Me.Dirty = False` at the top of command5_Click. Requerying the recordset is overkill - you lose your scroll position and your current record.

When you have a continuous form, data is written out to the database when focus is moved from the current record to a different record. This ***does not happen*** when you move focus to a control in the header or footer. This is by design, as it is a useful feature. Here's why:

Suppose you had a 3rd field in your database, a text field called "essay" where you could write a 10-line essay all about the color. The field is too big to show on the continuous part of the form, so you add a bound textbox to the form footer. As you move up and down through the color records, the essay for the current color will show at the bottom of the form. ***And it will be editable***. When you click on the Essay textbox, the current record is still being edited. The current record can have bound controls in the header, detail and footer, and edits in any of those places will all be written to the DB simultaneously.

When you move focus to an ***unbound*** control (such as command5), it's no different. The current record is still the current record, even though none of its bound controls currently have the focus.

Whenever you want the current record to remain the current record, but to force its edits to be written to the DB, you use `Me.Dirty = False`.

As to why command5 only works the first time you click it? I have no idea!